# New SP separate from other SP farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, deployment, 2016, server-farm

I want to deploy SP2016 on-premise in my company, but I want to do so on a separate SQL server and independent from the other two SP 2013 and SP2010 deployments. Basically a new, separate farm for the SP2016.

The SP 2013 and SP 2010 are deployed on separate SQL server each. (SP2013 - SQL1 and SP2010 - SQL2)

I'm worried that the new deployment will hit a conflict with the other farms and the TECHNET guides didn't help me find the answer 100%.

Did anyway try this before or experienced difficulties during this type of deployment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By creating a separate farm, with a dedicated SQL server.. what could possible conflict with the other deployments? There is no relations between them more then sharing the bandwidth and the AD and domain i guess? You should be fine.

Comment: My thoughts exacly user19952, but I want to make sure since the deployment setup sees the other farms as well and I don't want them to connect in any way. You know the saying: "Measure twice, cut once." something like that in this case.

Comment: When deploying a new server/farm, you specify which database server to use.. so i don't see how you accidentally could connect to a 2010, or 2013 database, and even if you do, you should see a lot of errors getting thrown at you. But, working with SharePoint, there is nothing wrong with your mindset. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help. I tried finding the "Accept answer" button but didn't find it.  I will check again later. Props to you!

Comment: I did not answer your question in the formal way, it was more of my point of view. However, i think this site will be a huge help when setting up your 2016 evaluation farm. :)

Comment: Just to add...You can keep the different service accounts for each farm to avoid any confusion.